# Next EditText receiving focus via soft keyboard on Android

Tags: android

I have six `EditText` (input type set to decimal) fields in three `LinearLayouts` organised as follows:

```
ET1        ET2
--------------
ET3        ET4
--------------
ET5        ET6
```

When the user presses the '>' symbol on the soft-keyboard there are two distinct paths:

```
ET1 -> ET3 -> ET5
```

and

```
ET2 -> ET4 -> ET6
```

Once reached `ET5` or `ET6` the '>' symbol turns into a checkmark, that, if pressed, closes the soft keyboard.

I think Android just tried to guess how to move from one field to the other, but it's wrong. I would like a single path

```
ET1->ET2->ET3-> .... ->ET6
```

I have tried to find some documentation on this, but I was only able to find references to `android:nextFocusUp/down/forward/...`, which do not make much sense to me in my context (I tried `forward` with no success).

I think I understood how to obtain that programmatically, but it's not worth the effort of doing it.

Is there any way to define the transversal path in the XML file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using `android:nextFocusdown`, in this manner

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText1" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText3" >
            </EditText>
..
..
..
..//last editText


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </EditText>
```